# Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, middleware, redux-thunk

I have the following code which is throwing the error of the actions must be plain objects.i think the problem is with redux thunk but i am not able to rectify it.

action file-

```
import axios from "axios";
export const addBiller = (biller = {}) => {
return async dispatch => {
const res = await axios.post("/api/biller", biller);

dispatch({ type: "ADD_BILLER", payload: res.data });
};
};
```

my store-

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import billerReducer from "../reducers/Billers";
import userReducer from "../reducers/User";
import billReducer from "../reducers/Bills";
import authReducer from "../reducers/Auth";
import reduxThunk from "redux-thunk";
export default () => {
 const store = createStore(
combineReducers(
  {
    Billers: billerReducer,
    Users: userReducer,
    Bills: billReducer,
    Auth: authReducer
  },
  applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)
  )
  );
 return store;
 };
```

the backend file-

```
 const mongoose = require("mongoose");
 const Biller = mongoose.model("biller");
 module.exports = app => {
 app.post("/api/biller", async (req, res) => {
 const { billerName, billerDescription } = req.body;
 const biller = new Biller({
  billerName: billerName,
  billerDescription: billerDescription
  });
   biller = await biller.save();
    res.send(biller);
    });
     };
```

my reducer-

```
   const BillerDefaultState = [];
   const billerReducer = (state = BillerDefaultState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_BILLER":
     return [...state, action.biller];
     default:
      return state;
     }
     };
     export default billerReducer;
```

Comment: Your createStore method is wrong. Complete your combineReducers function and then pass middlewares as the 3rd argument to your createStore method.

Comment: The second argument to [createStore](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/createstore) is pre-loaded state. vampurrmaid's solution should help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's the way Thunk is initialized into the store - the enhancer should be the third argument.

From the [docs](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/api/createStore.md)

> createStore(reducer, [preloadedState], [enhancer])
>
> [enhancer] (Function): The store enhancer. You may optionally specify it to enhance the store with third-party capabilities such as middleware, time travel, persistence, etc. The only store enhancer that ships with Redux is applyMiddleware().

Here's how I initialize it in my project, noting that I've imported the `reducers` object in a similar way that you've defined it in your code:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk'

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose
const store = createStore(reducers, {}, composeEnhancers(
  applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)
))
```

Note that I've also added in `Redux Devtools`, though if you don't want this additional functionality, [you can just stick to `compose`](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/compose), or `applyMiddleware` on its own if there's nothing to compose.