# Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions. Redux/Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

When trying to add product to user favorites I am getting this error. Although the state of redux is getting updated properly.
I have used Redux Thunk for Authentication, but I was trying to avoid adding to many extra reducers as the add a lot of code just for one function; and start using productService.js file.

userSlice.js

```
import {
  createAction,
  createSlice,
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {
  loginUser,
  registerUser,
} from "../actions/authActions";
import { getWithExpiry } from "../../utils/setStorage";

export const addFavoritesError = createAction(
  "addFavoritesError"
);

const savedUserInfo = getWithExpiry("userInfo")
  ? getWithExpiry("userInfo")
  : null;
const savedToken = getWithExpiry("userToken")
  ? getWithExpiry("userToken")
  : null;

const initialValue = {
  isLoading: false,
  userInfo: savedUserInfo,
  userToken: savedToken,
  error: null,
  success: false,
};

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState: initialValue,
  reducers: {
    login: (state) => {
      loginUser().then((res) => {
        // history.pushState('/');
      });
    },

    logOut: (state) => {
      return {
        ...state.initialState,
        isLoading: false,
        userInfo: null,
        userToken: null,
        error: null,
        success: false,
      };
    },
    signUp: (state) => {
      registerUser().then((res) => {
        // history.pushState('/');
      });
    },

    addFavorites: (state, action) => {
      return {
        ...state,
        userInfo: {
          ...state.userInfo,
          favorites: [...action.payload],
        },
      };
    },
  },
  extraReducers: {
    // 1 login user
    [loginUser.pending]: (state) => {
      state.isLoading = true;
      state.error = null;
    },

    [loginUser.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.success = true;
      state.userInfo = payload.data.user;
      state.userToken = payload.token;
    },

    [loginUser.rejected]: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.error = payload;
    },

    // 2 register user

    [registerUser.pending]: (state) => {
      state.isLoading = true;
      state.error = null;
    },

    [registerUser.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.success = true;
      state.userInfo = payload;
      state.userToken = payload.token;
    },

    [registerUser.rejected]: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.error = payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { logOut, addFavorites } = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice.reducer
```

userService.js

```
import apiActions from "../../utils/api";
import { addFavorites, addFavoritesError } from "../slices/userSlice";

export const AddProdToFavorites = async (dispatch, user_id, prod_id) => {
  try {
    // api call
    const data = await apiActions.addProdToUserFav(user_id, prod_id);
    dispatch(addFavorites(data));
  } catch {
    dispatch(addFavoritesError());
  }
};`
```

ProductCard.js

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch} from "react-redux";
import { AddProdToFavorites} from "../../../store/services/userService";


function DestinationsDisplayCard(props) {
  const { userToken, name, price} = props;
  const [favored, setFavored] = useState(false);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const addItemtoFav = useCallback(() => {
    setFavored((currrent) => !currrent);
    dispatch(AddProdToFavorites(dispatch, userToken, prodId));
  }, [favored]);

const removeItemFromFav = useCallback(() => {}, [favored]);

return (
  <div className="productCard">
        <p>{name}</p>
        <p>${price}</p>
        {userToken ? (
          <button
            onClick={favored ? removeItemFromFav : addItemtoFav}
          >
          </button>
        ) : null}
      </div>

)
}
```

authActions.js

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import apiActions from "../../utils/api";
import { setWithExpiry } from "../../utils/setStorage";

export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/login",
  async ({ email, password }, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const data = await apiActions.loginUser(
        email,
        password
      );

      setWithExpiry("userToken", data.token, 900000);
      setWithExpiry("userInfo", data.data.user, 900000);

      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response && error.response.data.message) {
        return rejectWithValue(error.response.data.message);
      } else {
        return rejectWithValue(error.message);
      }
    }
  }
);

export const registerUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/register",
  async (
    { name, email, password },
    { rejectWithValue }
  ) => {
    console.log("thunk - register", name, email, password);
    try {
      const data = await apiActions.registerUser(
        name,
        email,
        password
      );
      localStorage.setItem("userToken", data.token);

      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response && error.response.data.message) {
        return rejectWithValue(error.response.data.message);
      } else {
        return rejectWithValue(error.message);
      }
    }
  }
);
```

api.js

```
import axios from "axios";
const baseURL = "<<the url for api>>";

const apiActions = {
addProdToUserFav: async (user_id, prod_id) => {
    const res = await axios.post(
      `${baseURL}/v1/user/addFavorite`,
      {
        userId: user_id,
        prodId: prod_id,
      }
    );
    return res.data.data.user.favorites;
  },
// this endpoint returns a list of object [{product2}{product2}] (with name, price, discount, etc)
}
```

I expected that state.userInfo.favorites to update, which it does, but I am getting this error.

```
Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
VM41:1 Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
    at Object.performAction (<anonymous>:1:41504)
    at k (<anonymous>:3:1392)
    at s (<anonymous>:3:5102)
    at serializableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:210:1
    at index.js:20:1
    at Object.dispatch (immutableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:264:1)
    at dispatch (<anonymous>:6:7391)
    at DestinationsDisplay.card.jsx:23:1
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49558293/error-actions-must-be-plain-objects-use-custom-middleware-for-async-actions)

Comment: if you're using redux toolkit, use their `createAsyncThunk` function. You're getting the error though because you're trying to do async fetch operations in your login and signup reducers, which is not valid redux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues with the way you are trying to use regular reducer functions to handle asynchronous side-effects, and dispatching objects to the store that are neither action objects nor asynchronous action creators, e.g. Thunks.

`AddProdToFavorites` is a regular function and should be rewritten to use Redux-Toolkit's `createAsyncThunk`.

The suggested/recommended patter is to return *directly* the fetched data or rejected Promise with error value, and use the state slice's `extraReducers` to handle the state updates. Remember that with RTK you can write ***mutable*** state updates, you don't need to shallow copy all the state.

```js
import { createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import apiActions from "../../utils/api";

export const AddProdToFavorites = createAsyncThunk(
  "addProdToFavorites",
  async ({ user_id, prod_id }, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      // api call
      const data = await apiActions.addProdToUserFav(user_id, prod_id);
      return data;
    } catch(error) {
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  },
);
```

```js
const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState: initialValue,
  reducers: {
    ...
    addFavorites: (state, action) => {
      state.userInfo.favorites = action.payload;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    ...
  },
});
```

or if you are really wanting to write and keep the extra actions, use the second argument to the thunk to access the `dispatch` function and dispatch your other actions to the store. Handle these actions in the regular `reducers` with the same mutable state update.

```js
import { createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import apiActions from "../../utils/api";
import { addFavorites, addFavoritesError } from "../slices/userSlice";

export const AddProdToFavorites = createAsyncThunk(
  "addProdToFavorites",
  async ({ user_id, prod_id }, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      // api call
      const data = await apiActions.addProdToUserFav(user_id, prod_id);
      thunkApi.dispatch(addFavorites(data));
    } catch(error) {
      thunkApi.dispatch(addFavoritesError(error));
    }
  },
);
```

```js
const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState: initialValue,
  reducers: {
    ...
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addCase(AddProdToFavorites.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.userInfo.favorites = action.payload;
      })
      ...
  },
});
```

Dispatching `AddProdToFavorites` action:

```
function DestinationsDisplayCard({ userToken, name, price }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  const [favored, setFavored] = useState(false);

  const addItemtoFav = () => {
    setFavored((favored) => !favored);
    dispatch(AddProdToFavorites({ userToken, prodId }));
  };

  const removeItemFromFav = () => {};

  return (
    <div className="productCard">
      <p>{name}</p>
      <p>${price}</p>
      {userToken && (
        <button
          onClick={favored ? removeItemFromFav : addItemtoFav}
        >
          ...
        </button>
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

In `authSlice` the `login` and `signup` actions/reducers are invalid. Reducer functions are to be ***pure, synchronous*** functions. These two actions should also be Thunks, and the ***UI*** should handle chaining or `await`-ing them to settle in order to issue the additional side-effect, e.g. the navigation. It looks like `loginUser` and `registerUser` are *already* RTK Thunks, so remove the `login` and `signup` actions/reducers from the `authSlice` and handle the asynchronous logic in the calling function.

Example:

```js
const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState: initialValue,
  reducers: {
    logOut: (state) => {
      return {
        ...state.initialState,
        isLoading: false,
        userInfo: null,
        userToken: null,
        error: null,
        success: false,
      };
    },
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addCase(AddProdToFavorites.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.userInfo.favorites = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(loginUser.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
        state.error = null;
      })
      .addCase(loginUser.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.success = true;
        state.userInfo = payload.data.user;
        state.userToken = payload.token;
      })
      .addCase(loginUser.rejected, (state, { payload }) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.error = payload;
      })
      .addCase(registerUser.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
        state.error = null;
      })
      .addCase(registerUser.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.success = true;
        state.userInfo = payload;
        state.userToken = payload.token;
      })
      .addCase(registerUser.rejected, (state, { payload }) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.error = payload;
      });
  },
});
```

Unwrap the returned resolved Promise to handle the fulfilled/rejected status.

```js
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();

  const loginHandler = async () => {
    try {
      await dispatch(loginUser()).unwrap();
      history.push("/");
    } catch(error) {
      // handle login errors, etc...
    }
  };

  ...
};
```

or

```js
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();

  const loginHandler = () => {
    dispatch(loginUser()).unwrap()
      .then(() => {
        history.push("/");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // handle login errors, etc...
      });
  };

  ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer, it solved the problem, including the working I was getting about "redux builder", I will post this warning here for future reference. 

<--
    "The object notation for `createSlice.extraReducers` is deprecated, and will be removed 
    in RTK 2.0. Please use the 'builder callback' notation instead: https://redux- 
    toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice"
-->

Comment: I will work my reputation up, so I can upvote your answer